# What is the conjugate of the conjugate of a function?

Tags: definition, convex-optimization

Let $f$ be a convex function.

Then the conjugate of $f$ is defined as $f^*(y) \equiv \sup_{x}(y^Tx - f(x))$

How is the conjugate of the conjugate defined $f^{**}(y) \equiv ?$

Edit for question clarity:

Is it $f^{**} : Z \rightarrow \Bbb R$ by $f^{**}(z) = \sup_{y}(z^Ty - f^*(y))$? Is it $f^{**}(z) = \sup_{x}(z^Tx - f^*(y))$?  Is the domain changed every time you take a conjugate or is $Z=Y$?

Comment: Why make this any more difficult than it needs to be? $f^{**}$ is simply the conjugation operation applied twice. The conjugate of the conjugate.

Comment: If $f$ is proper and lower semicontinuous, then $f^{**}=f$. See any decent text on convex analysis.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Can you show what results when the operation is applied twice?  I'm having trouble understanding what it looks like.  If $f: X \rightarrow \Bbb R$ and $f^*(y) : Y \rightarrow \Bbb R$ by $f^*(y) = \sup_x(y^Tx - f(x))$, then what results from applying the operation a second time?  Is it $f^{**} : Z \rightarrow \Bbb R$ by $f^{**}(z) = \sup_{y}(z^Ty - f^*(y))$? Is it $f^{**}(z) = \sup_{x}(z^Tx - f^*(y))$?  Is the domain changed every time you take a conjugate or is $Z=Y$?

Comment: See max_zorn's comment.

Comment: @MichaelGrant What if $f$ is not proper and lower semicontinuous?

Comment: I suggest doing a couple of simple 1-D experiments and see if you can conclude anything.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I am unable to do any experiments as I do not understand how to take the conjugate twice.  I do not know whether $f^{**}(z)$ is defined as $\sup_y(z^Ty - f^*(y))$ or $\sup_x(z^Tx - f^*(y))$.  And I do not understand the relationship between $Z$ and $Y$ for the domains of the second and first conjugate of the function $f$.  If you could clarify which is the proper definition this would answer my question.

Comment: I refer you to my first comment. Compute the conjugate once. Fully simplify. Then when you are done, take the conjugate of that. The fact that you seem to be trying to tie the two conjugations together suggests you might not yet understand the single conjugate itself, in which case you are getting too far ahead of yourself.

Comment: @MichaelGrant If $f$ is a function $f : X \rightarrow \Bbb R$, then, by definition, $f^*(y) = \sup_x(y^Tx - f(x))$ where $y \in Y$ is the set of points in $\Bbb R^n$ such that the $\sup$ is finite.  You say to simplify this.  How can this be simplified any further?

Comment: Try a specific function.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you could please just tell me which definition I provided is correct I would understand what I am misunderstanding and it would answer my question.

Comment: The first definition is correct. You are given $f^*$, and compute the conjugate of it: $f^{**}(z)=(f^*)^*(z)=\mathrm{sup}_y z^T y - f^*(y)$. (The second definition you provided does not make much sense; what would "y" be there?)